# How to use decimal in quantity fields in WooCommerce for certain categories?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I found the code what I want to use on my woocommerce shop, but I want to use it only for certain categories from my shop. Can someone explain how I can do it?

```
// Add min value to the quantity field (default = 1)
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');
function min_decimal($val) {
    return 0.1;
}
 
// Add step value to the quantity field (default = 1)
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
    return 0.1;
}
 
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
 
// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');
 
// Add unit price fix when showing the unit price on processed orders
add_filter('woocommerce_order_amount_item_total', 'unit_price_fix', 10, 5);
function unit_price_fix($price, $order, $item, $inc_tax = false, $round = true) {
    $qty = (!empty($item['qty']) && $item['qty'] != 0) ? $item['qty'] : 1;
    if($inc_tax) {
        $price = ($item['line_total'] + $item['line_tax']) / $qty;
    } else {
        $price = $item['line_total'] / $qty;
    }
    $price = $round ? round( $price, 2 ) : $price;
    return $price;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: anyone can help me here?

Comment: Try using `is_product_category('foo')`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49501582/make-calculations-on-woocommerce-product-price-html-and-display-it

Answer (score 0):

check this sample code :

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal', 10, 2);
function min_decimal($val, WC_Product $product) {
if(get_the_category($product->id) == 12) { // 12 = ID on the category you want it to work with
return 0.1;
}
return 1;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'step_decimal', 10, 2);
function step_decimal($val, WC_Product $product) {
if(get_the_category($product->id) == 12) { // 12 = ID on the category you want it to work with
return 0.1;
}

return 1;
}
```